# javascript window location href without hash?

Tags: javascript, location, substring

I have:

```
var uri = window.location.href;
```

That provides `http://example.com/something#hash`

What's the best and easiest way to get the entire path without the `#hash`?

```
uri    = http://example.com/something#hash
nohash = http://example.com/something
```

I tried using `location.origin+location.pathname` which doesn't work in every browser. I tried using `location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname` which looks like kind of a crappy solution to me.

What is the best and easiest way to do so? maybe I query for location.hash and try to substr() this from the uri?

Comment: BTW, if your doing this just to link to a `#section` on the same page, just set the link href to `#section`. You don't need to get the page's base url then concatenate the hash on the end.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname` is the correct syntax if you do not care about port number or querystring

If you do care:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

```
location.protocol+'//'+
  location.host+
  location.pathname+
 (location.search?location.search:"")
```

or

```
location.protocol+'//'+
  location.hostname+
 (location.port?":"+location.port:"")+
  location.pathname+
 (location.search?location.search:"")
```

You can also just do a `location.href.replace(location.hash,"")`
It will remove EVERYTHING from the FIRST # and on regardless of other hash characters in the string

Alternatively create a [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.somepage.com/page.hmtl#anchor") //(location.href);
console.log(url)
url.hash="";
console.log(url)
```

Comment: You lost the query string (if there was one) there

Comment: Seems like location.host is including port.

Comment: That last bit about `.replace(location.hash,'')` is brilliant and just what I was trawling for.

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin - should still work: `var url = "http://example.com#example";
var lnk = document.createElement("a");
lnk.href=url;
alert(lnk.hash);`

Comment: @mplungjan oh, got it, hash property has leading `#`. Thanks!

Comment: location.href.replace(location.hash,"") will not work properly because: http://example.com#example# will give '' as hash; http://example.com#example#a will give '#a' as hash; window.location.href.split('#')[0] is a correct solution.

Comment: The first solution has an issue: URLs like `https://example.com/foo?` will get transformed to ones without the question mark. Sometimes this causes issues. Your last method using the `URL` constructor seems to work fine, though, thanks!

Answer (score 94):

```
var uri = window.location.href.split("#")[0];

// Returns http://example.com/something

var hash = window.location.hash;

// Returns #hash
```

Comment: The hash sign isn't included in the second part of that array

Comment: I did include a fix! :-)

Comment: This doesn't work. `"foo#bar#baz".split("#") == "bar"`

Comment: For hash, just use `location.hash`.

Answer (score 21):

```
location.href.replace(location.hash,"")
```

Comment: `(location+'').href.replace(location.hash,"")` works in firefox (location is not a regular string)

Comment: But care that `location.hash` is '' when url is somehting.com/#

Comment: Surprisingly to me, this will not break if `location.hash` is contained elsewhere in the URL. For example, "http://www.example.com/#example". Because `location.hash` contains the leading "#". Except, when the hash is blank, as pointed out above.

Comment: location.hash will contain EVERYTHING from the FIRST # to the end and ignore ANY subsequestion (illegal) url characters like #
https://plungjan.name/SO/testhref.html - I tested because my answer was voted down

Answer (score 9):

Is the universal way also the smaller?

```
location.href.split(/\?|#/)[0]
```

Comment: That also removes the query params, not just the hash. To remove only the hash: `location.href.split('#')[0]`

Answer (score 8):

Shorter solutions:

- without query string and hash `location.href.split(location.search||location.hash||/[?#]/)[0]`
- only without hash `location.href.split(location.hash||"#")[0]`

(I usually use the first one)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this answer:

```js
`${window.location.origin}${window.location.pathname}${window.location.search}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of letting native code do the heavy lifting as much as possible. I'd come to think that a browser can recognize the parts of URLs better than us doing a best guess. So here's another variant for your consideration:

```
new URL('#', location.href).slice(0, -1)
```

I guess this needs a litte explanation: What's happening is we're constructing a URL object with an empty hash on the current URL as base, i.e. if there is a hash, it gets replace by an empty one. We then remove the last character ('#') from the implicitly cast string (href of the URL object).

Answer (score 0):

ES2020:

```js
let [uri, hash] = location.href.split("#");
console.log(uri, hash);

location.hash = "#myhash";

[uri, hash] = location.href.split("#");
console.log(uri, hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this short one-liners which directly return the wanted result instead of creating an array.

**To remove only the hash (#hash):**

```
location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '')
```

**To remove both the hash (#hash) and the query params (?query=value&...):**

```
location.href.replace(/(\?|#).*$/, '')
```

This is regex (`/.../`) for replacing from the first ? (`\?`) or (`(...|...)`) # (`#`), all characters (`.*`) until the end of the string (`$`), by an empty string (`''`).

Answer (score -3):

```js
location.href = window.location.href.split("write here your code to delete in your URL")[0] + "write here your final destination";
```

Comment: Hi @Vittrix welcome to SO ! Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) , also try to include some notes about what your answer does differently or better compared to the already accepted answer !