# Alfresco share site auto refreshing

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How to auto refresh the share site? Now when someone post an answer in share discussion the user has to refresh the page in order to view the answer. How to auto refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited `toolbar.get.html` in `tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\discussions`. I added the following meta tag

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="100">`. This is working.

Comment: @alfrescian is this Okay?

Answer (score 1):

There is no pre-defined auto-refresh component in Share. You'll have to code it yourself.

1. Option 1: Auto-Poll the server every x seconds via JavaScript, e.g. use YAHOO.lang.later(...)
2. Option 2: Write your own Alfresco Policy to trigger a Server-Sent Events + consume such event in Share
3. Option 3: Introduce WebSockets

All Options will require deep knowledge of JavaScript in the Browser, especially YUI & Alfresco's custom Share components & utils. Option 2 & 3 will additionally require deep knowledge of Java & Alfresco's Java Foundation API.

Comment: Can I use a java script and set the rule in the site ?

Comment: you can use a javascript rule to trigger the SSE in option 2 or to emit() in option 3.
But both cases are not trivial & JavaScript only as you'll to add SSE/websocket capabilities to Alfresco...

Comment: I think location.reload(); will do the reload of the page rite?

Comment: yes, there are several options to reload the current page: -> e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967532/window-location-reload-not-working-for-firefox-and-and-chrome
Thought you would like to refresh the page for every user if there is a new answer...

Comment: Ya I created the script but how to link the script to the site? I tried `manage rule` but I dont find option to use this script

Comment: a rule is the wrong layer. A rule runs in the repo layer. You'll have to change the JS that runs in the browser -> one of the js-Files in share\components\discussions. But please make yourself familar with Share/SURF customizations & subcomponents before. It's NOT recommended to just change the original file

Comment: But the issue is if the entire page reload then it will be really annoying rit? I need to reload the particular area to be reloaded

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript, YUI & XHR in general?

Comment: No I am a fresher and I have basic knowledge in C and CPP only

Comment: Can you tell me in which js files do I need to modify

Comment: don't know - one of the js in share\components\discussions-

Comment: don't know, because I still didn't understand your problem in detail...
What Alfresco version do your use?
Which page (URL) do your use to add an reply?
Which data should be loaded but is not loaded?
Are you sure that we're talking about the dicusssions site-component?
Normally a reply is visible & loaded after adding it - for the current user, other users need to refresh.

Comment: I am using 4.2e CE. The url is like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/site/sample/discussions-topicview?topicId=post-1394454079256_9467&listViewLinkBack=true` I need to refresh this page at regular interval.

Comment: Still I am not clear on this and I am stuck on this. I need something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxFhviithUs 
Watch from 11:00 to 12:00 in the video. When user type an answer it is updated for every users

Answer (score 0):

I made a polling timer to update specific data instead of reloading the whole page

http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-presence/source/browse/share/source/web/presence/components/head/polling-timer.js

However this is more work.

Comment: I deployed it but I cant find it in admin tools

Comment: However I find it in share/page/modules/deploy

Comment: It is just a javascript impl., you need to use it for the data you need updated. In the presence module it retrieves updated site-members presence status, and therefore does not reload the whole page ...