# window.location.reload working randomly on various devices & browsers

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, css

I've tried looking around for an answer to this and tried many variations of `window.location.reload` although to no avail.

What I have the user doing is, they press a button to create a date which should then refresh the page as soon as it's been confirmed to then show the new date on the home screen.

This works on any browser I've tried (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera) on the desktop although when it comes to mobile devices, the results are quite random.

I've tried this on;

- ASUS Tablet (Doesn't work on Chrome or built in browser)
- iPad 4th Generation (Doesn't work on Chrome or Safari)
- Samsung S6 (Works on Chrome)
- Samsung A3 (Doesn't work on Chrome or built in browser)

Here is the code for the button

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-xs-12 form-group  ">
  <button onClick="window.location.reload();" type="button" class="btn form-btns btn-primary" id="submit_btn" title="Submit Data" data-placement="bottom" >
   <i onClick="window.location.reload();" id="submit_check_icon" class="fa fa-send "></i>  Save
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on what the cause of this behaviour could be?

**If I've missed any vital information out, please let me know and I'll revise my question.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.reload` works with all browsers and there are no known issues with it.
The problem might be that your browser is displaying cached data.

The `window.location.reload` accepts a parameter `forcedReload`

[**forcedReload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

> Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always
>   be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the
>   browser may reload the page from its cache.

If this is not the case, then [you can force the refresh in another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967532/window-location-reload-not-working-for-firefox-and-chrome) like

`history.go(0);` or `location.href = location.href;`

Comment: Hey Hyyan, this was perfect - thanks for the explanations. The forcedReload didn't help although using location.href = location.href; works perfectly on all devices now, apart from iPad's Safari, not too much of an issue!

Comment: Unfortunately no of this suggestions works on mobile browsers (safari, Google chrome)...