# window.location.reload works fine in Chrome but not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, reload, mozilla

Iam working on reloading of a webpage after printing it in PDF Format.So after printing i provided a window.location.reload method.It works fine in Chrome but not on Firefox.How Can I get rid of this problem?

```
printDocument = () => {
  const { match } = this.props;
  const { orderNo } = match.params;
  this.setState({ showPickSheet: true }, () => {
    const printContents = document.getElementById("divToPrint").innerHTML;
    document.title = `PickSheet_${orderNo}`;
    const originalContents = document.body.innerHTMl;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    window.location.reload();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload
There it 
location.reload(forcedReload);
Add `true` into the reload function. it should work everywhere.

```
// Reload the current page without the browser cache
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Check out this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967532/window-location-reload-not-working-for-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 0):

This works in both chrome and firefox.

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: but it says unnecessary use of location

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload();
});
```

You can use this it works in both firefox and chrome