# Hide a CSS class only on homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

I'm trying to hide this class "mediad rh-flex-right-align" from my header only on HomePage.
This class must appear on every other page.

I tried Javascript to achieve this, but it's not working so I probably made a mistake in these lines:

```
if (document.url == "https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/")
{
document.getElementsByClassName("mediad rh-flex-right-align")
[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome to hide a CSS class on Homepage

Comment: Why can't you try using jQuery ?

Comment: It would be easier to just include css or js in the home page that hides it.

Comment: Just add the css as internal css in home page

Comment: @Abinthaha Don't be that guy.  https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: You need to provide a **clear problem statement**, which "not working" is not. What, precisely, isn't working (you've got two separate statements in your code, which one doesn't do what you expect)? Are there any error messages? If you add a logging statement, can you confirm what the value of `document.url`? Is it what you expect? Do you enter the `if` statement?

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Issue solved below this post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `url` attribute in `document` but there is a `URL` one.

So you can either use `document.URL` or `window.location.href`.

I've had problems with `document.URL` in the past so prefer the second one.

Edit : Note that this solution will not work if your URL contains a hash (ex: `comparer-acheter.fr/#hash`). It will also not work if the name of your website changes. If you want to check if you are on the homepage, you can use this :

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/') {
    // you are on the homepage
}
```

You will have more informations on how `locations` work on this post : [javascript window location href without hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818269/javascript-window-location-href-without-hash)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working perfectly. here the corrected code:
            if (window.location.href == "https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("rh-flex-right-align") .[0].style.display = 'none';

Comment: @Flo Be aware that is will not work if you have a hash in the URL (ex: "comparer-acheter.fr/#myHash"). If you just want to check if you are on the homepage, you can also use `window.location.pathname == '/'`. I updated my answer to reflect this.